# Cannot with scramble with the button

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, shuffle

My program is a scrambling application that is supposed to shuffle my sentence when i press the 'Scramble' button. But instead, it shuffles my sentence whenever i refresh the page, and when I click on the 'Scramble' button, nothing happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Sentence Scramble and Sequencer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Second.css" />
<script src="chinesesentence.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



</head>

<body>
<center>
<img src = "http://imageshack.com/a/img842/1461/otd4.jpg"/>
    <h1>ChineseSentences</h1>


<?php
// Connect to database server
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die (mysql_error ());

// Select database
mysql_select_db("login") or die(mysql_error());

// Get data from the database depending on the value of the id in the URL
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM sentences WHERE id 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;";

//create an array with numbers 1-4
$order = array(1,2,3,4);

//shuffle them in random order
shuffle($order);

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

// Loop the recordset $rs
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
// Write the data of the person
//Display all the array values from 0-3 (array index starts from 0)
echo "<dt>Sentence:</dt><dd>" . $row[$order[0]] . " " . $row[$order[1]] . " " .    
$row[$order[2]] . " " . $row[$order[3]] ."</dd>";
}
// Close the database connection
mysql_close();
?>

  <button id="showcontent">Scramble</button>
   <div id="content"></div>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i find the question scrambled. a html button with no js\form will do nothing by it self

Comment: can i have a look? @Dagon

Answer (score 0):

You could:

a. Put it inside a form:

```
<form method="POST">
    <button id="showcontent">Scramble</button>
</form>
```

b. Or just put an `onclick` refresh page event on it

```
<button id="showcontent" onclick="window.location.reload()">Scramble</button>
```

This button can be applied like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
// since you dont have a var_dump() of sentences, so il just create a dummy data
// for example this is a select query from db
$sentences_from_db = array('The quick brown fox word1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor word2', 'The little red riding hood word3', 'i like to play the piano word4');
function shuffle_sentences($sentence) {
    shuffle($sentence);
    $get_current = reset($sentence);
    $words = explode(' ', $get_current);
    shuffle($words);
    $final_shuffled = implode(' ', $words);
    $_SESSION['current_sentence'] = $final_shuffled;
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['current_sentence'])) {
    shuffle_sentences($sentences_from_db);
}

// scramble current sentence
if(isset($_POST['scramble'])) {
    $current_sentence = explode(' ', $_SESSION['current_sentence']);
    shuffle($current_sentence);
    $_SESSION['current_sentence'] = implode(' ', $current_sentence);
}

// generate new word
if(isset($_POST['new'])) {
    shuffle_sentences($sentences_from_db);
}

?>

<form method="POST">
    <h1><?php echo $_SESSION['current_sentence']; ?></h1>
    <button type="submit" name="scramble">Scamble</button>
    <button type="submit" name="new">New word</button>
</form>
```

Comment: what should i link with the form? @kevinabelita

Comment: @user3678617 you dont need to put anything in the form just the button itself. did you try these solutions?

Comment: After adding the form, i can scramble every time i click the button. For example, a sentence which is store in my database "I like to play the piano", i want it to scramble only after clicking the button. So after the button may be " like to I play piano the". @kevinabelita

Comment: Yes, but I want it to be in the exact sentence only when I click on the scramble button the sentence then will scramble from "I like to play the piano" to " like to I play piano the".

Comment: @user3678617 maybe you should have put inside the question, the contents of `$row` so that i looked into that earlier.

Comment: When I open my page, the sentence it retrieved from the database is already shuffled. And I when I clicked on ‘Scramble’, it’s supposed to scramble the current sentence but instead, it retrieves a new ID and shuffle a new sentence from my database. @kevinabelita

Comment: @user3678617 ah okay, you didnt say that earlier, you can just use sessions for that, upon first load, what you have to do is set it inside a session, then after click of the button, check if its set, if its set, shuffle the one that is saved inside the session

Comment: So sorry about that. May i know what you mean by session? Any examples? @kevinabelita

Comment: @user3678617 i already updated my answer, actually this counts as another answer, but anyway, check the current edit

Comment: I have tried the code that you give but both the ' Scramble' and 'New word button actually do the same job. It just shuffle different id and shuffle the sentence each time i click the button. @kevinabelita

Comment: @user3678617 i added `session_start();` above the php code, maybe you also didn't add it.

Comment: Take a look at the answer below. There is also a link which how it actually look like. I wanted it to select a sentence id and show what is fill in the column of that row. Retrieve in same order, for example 'I like to play the piano.' then after i press 'scramble it will then shuffle that sentence to 'play I the piano like to'. @kevinabelita

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>HelloWorld</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Second.css" />
<script src="chinesesentence.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



  </head>

  <body>
<center>
    <h1>Sentences</h1>


  <?php
  // Connect to database server
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die (mysql_error ());

  // Select database
  mysql_select_db("login") or die(mysql_error());

  // Get data from the database depending on the value of the id in the URL
  $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM sentences WHERE id 
  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;";

  //create an array with numbers 1-4
  $order = array(1,2,3,4);

  //shuffle them in random order
  shuffle($order);

  $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

  // Loop the recordset $rs
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
  // Write the data of the person
  //Display all the array values from 0-3 (array index starts from 0)
 echo "<dt>Sentence:</dt><dd>" . $row[$order[0]] . " " . $row[$order[1]] . " " .
 $row[$order[2]] . " " . $row[$order[3]] ."</dd>";
  }


  // since you dont have a var_dump() of sentences, so il just create a dummy data
  // for example this is a select query from db
  $sentences_from_db = array('My name is Jane', 'What are you doing?', 'Hello, how      
  are you?', 'I Love you!');
  function shuffle_sentences($sentence) {
  shuffle($sentence);
  $get_current = reset($sentence);
 $words = explode(' ', $get_current);
 shuffle($words);
 $final_shuffled = implode(' ', $words);
 $_SESSION['current_sentence'] = $final_shuffled;
  }

  if(!isset($_SESSION['current_sentence'])) {
  shuffle_sentences($sentences_from_db);
  }

  // scramble current sentence
  if(isset($_POST['scramble'])) {
  $current_sentence = explode(' ', $_SESSION['current_sentence']);
  shuffle($current_sentence);
  $_SESSION['current_sentence'] = implode(' ', $current_sentence);
  }

  // generate new word
  if(isset($_POST['new'])) {
  shuffle_sentences($sentences_from_db);
  }


  // Close the database connection
  mysql_close();
  ?>


  <center>
  <form method="POST">
  <h1><?php echo $_SESSION['current_sentence']; ?></h1>
  <button type="submit" name="scramble">Scamble</button>
  <button type="submit" name="new">New word</button>
  </form>




   </center>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Click this website to see how it looks like: 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4iuo.png